# Adding Rounded rectangle css over text in Wordpress Navigation Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, navigationbar

I am trying to update Default Navigation menu on Wordpress Astra Theme and trying to add rounded rectangle in one of the menu as shown the photo, what should I add in the additional CSS Panel? Just started learning CSS and Wordpress yesterday, Im a newbie.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2HKF.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.round {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item round">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Add a class to the li item of the navbar or may be the element class to which rectange css has to be applied (in this case we want to round Link2 so I have given a class to  its li element called **round**) and then give the border to it followed by setting its radius shown in code.